# Prevent multiple popover windows open in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, popover, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I prevent to have multiple popover windows open? There should only be one open at a time.
Please see my punkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MjP1AlygixXHEOC3Jd5a

Within my plunkr, I use an updated ui-bootstrap 0.10 from jbruni (his plunkr is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/B2wEis?p=info)

When hovering about the two windows there is a chance that two popup windows are open at the same time. :(

Comment: Do you need a button in the popover? If not, you can change mouseover to mouseenter so that only one will be open at a time.  However, if you use mouseenter, then you can not get to the button in the popover.

Comment: I would like to get the button in the popover. Should it not be possible to prevent other popovers from showing up? If not, I think angularJS should be extended to be able to add behaviour to a popup.

Comment: I extended the tooltip part of ui-bootstrap in the part where the toolip is hidden and and observer looking for a new attribute:

attrs.$observe( prefix+'Popdown', function ( val ) {
              scope.tt_popdown = true;
            });

Comment: if ( scope.tt_animation ) {
                transitionTimeout = $timeout(removeTooltip, 500);
              } else if ( scope.tt_popdown ){
                vanishTimeout = $timeout(removeTooltip, 2000);
              } else {
                removeTooltip();
              }

Comment: The popover should dissapear after 2 seconds but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Do you have jQuery linked in?  I think the better approach would be to use mouseenter instead of mouseover and then add 2 second delay to the hide() action.  The mouseover event is used for both activating and deactivating the tooltip which gets confusing.

Comment: I wonder why hide action is not delayed. Do you have an idea why?
Thank you so far.

Comment: thanks Chi Row. Using mouseenter instead of mouseover solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you force off the animation, then the turn off delay seems to work.  Not a clean solution but sort of works.  You still have a chance to get two popovers at once since there is no function to delay the start of a new popover if there is one pending the turn off.

http://plnkr.co/edit/a8XHo7FKhrqv37mWTPBk?p=info

```
            if ( scope.tt_animation ) {
//                transitionTimeout = $timeout(removeTooltip, 500);
                  setTimeout(function(){scope.tt_animation=false;hide();},500);
              } else if ( scope.tt_popdown ){
                vanishTimeout = $timeout(removeTooltip, 2000);
              } else {0
                removeTooltip();
              }
```

Comment: That is great! So it depended on the animation? What specific part did you change?
Would make it a difference if parts of the popup window are focused somehow?

Comment: Line 2237 of popover.  I added the changed section above. It's not pretty but that was the only way I could think of to bypass the built in checking function.  Since it's getting ugly, maybe you should think about using a modal pop up instead if you need interaction with the popover.

Comment: Modal deactivates the background. That is something I don´t want.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a directive that wraps a popover control and uses the popover-is-open to trigger the popover opening and closeing.

To close any open popovers I trigger a custom event on the parent scope:

```
$scope.openPopup = function()
{
    $scope.$parent.$broadcast("multiSelectSinglePopoverInstanceEvent", {});
    $scope.isPopupOpen = !$scope.isPopupOpen;
}
```

In the custom popover controls controller I handle the event by closing the popover:

```
$scope.$on("multiSelectSinglePopoverInstanceEvent", function (event, args) {
    $scope.isPopupOpen = false;
});
```

This may help